# Getting "unmatched pseudo-class :lang" after updating Angular 14

Tags: node.js, node-modules, bootstrap-5, angular14, angular14upgrade

After updating to angular 14 and making build i am get this error.

> 1 rules skipped due to selector errors:
> .custom-file-input:lang(en)~.custom-file-label -> unmatched pseudo-class :lang

[image]

This is Index.html file

[image]

I am not understanding what the issue is. How can I sort out this error?

I upgraded both Angular and Bootstrap version

- Angular : 14
- Bootstrap : 4.6.0

Answer (score 0):

upgrade Bootstrap 5+ resolved this issue, works for me